# What is the best stream for Big Data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, sqoop

I want to do data analysis on my Oracle DB for BI. Now my stream is as follow:
**Source DB (Oracle)** => **Convert to HDFS file by using Sqoop** => **Use Spark to query on HDFS file** => **Write out put of Spark as csv File in Hadoop** => **Use Sqoop to convert to Destination Oracle DB** => **Present output data**

Is this an effective approach?
If not please recommend the most effective approach in very detail

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hive table by defining as external table in oracle. Then you can integrate the table to any BI tool.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37231_01/doc.20/e36961/sqlch.htm#BDCUG265

Comment: Does this way ensure performance compared to Spark? Or this is just another way to access Hadoop files?

Comment: Yes, this is just a way to access "hive tables" from oracle. Also, oracle does some caching however this is not a major performance improvement.